# Why can't I install libusb?

Tags: apt, usb

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and need to install libusb as part of a larger project. Here's the code I'm running:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb
```

and I get the error message

```
E: Unable to locate package libusb
```

I've checked other questions and tried their solutions. I tried updating my repositories to include the universe, but that didn't change anything. Am I missing something? Is there a new name for the package? Or how can I get it to install?

Comment: Here's a list of the various "libusb" packages available in 16.04: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libusb&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all

Answer (score 6):

I guess you want either:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-0.1-4
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0
```

depending on which version you prefer.